# Data Warehouse - difference between relational/dimensional modeling VS bottom-up/top-down design

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

I'm new to Data Warehouse and I would like to know what's the difference between **relational/dimensional modeling** VS **bottom-up/top-down design**.

Is it the same things? Or what do they have different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Relational/dimensional modeling" refers to database design.  More specifically, "relational modeling" (as promoted by Christopher J. Date and others) lends itself to OLTP database systems and "dimensional modeling" (as promoted by Ralph Kimball) lends itself to data warehouse systems.  Bill Inmon also has another approach to data warehouse database design so you may wish to search on him as well.
If you wish to look at the different data warehouse design approaches I would suggest searching on Kimball and then Inmon. If you look at those two men and their approaches, then you could say that Bill Inmon’s data warehouse approach is the top-down design methodology and Ralph Kimball’s data warehouse approach is the bottom-up design methodology.
There are books written about the differences so I will not go into great detail here.  Suffice it to say that Bill Inmon’s approach starts with a normalized data model while Ralph Kimball’s approach denormalizes that data model. That would be one difference between the two.